# How to setup Quarkus KeyValueStructuredArgument not working?

Tags: logging, quarkus

I want to log in a json format .

I am importing this.

```
import static io.quarkiverse.loggingjson.providers.KeyValueStructuredArgument.kv;

LOG.info("Some Error!{}", kv("key", "value"));
```

I would expect some json to be printed but it seems instead toString() method of kv() is called.

```
{
  "message": "Some error",
  "key": "value"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked a while ago but for anyone who has the same problem.
KeyValueStructuredArgument uses the Object's toString method, to be able to print kv inside the message like logback-logstash lib does, I have created a custom Class that implements StructuredArgument.

```
public class KeyValueArg implements StructuredArgument {
    private final String key;
    private final Object value;

    public KeyValueArg(String key, Object value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static StructuredArgument kv(String key, Object value) {
        return new KeyValueArg(key, value);
    }

    public void writeTo(JsonGenerator generator) throws IOException {
        generator.writeObjectField(this.key, this.value);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.key + "=" + this.value.toString();
    }
}
```